# Find integral with derivate from function values and other integral

Tags: calculus, integration

It is known that $f(x)$ has a continuous derivative with $f(6)=36$, $f(9)=243$ and $\int\limits^{9}_{6}{\frac{f(x)}{x^3}dx}=4$. Find the value of the integral $\int\limits^{9}_{6}{\frac{f'(x)}{x^2}dx}$.

The answer to the question is $10$ and I am really out of ideas on how to solve it. I have a feeling it is done with the FTC but I can't seem to get any results. Any tips?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts:
$$4=\int_6^9\frac{f(x)}{x^3}\,dx=-\frac12\left[\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\right]_6^9+\frac12\int_6^9\frac{f'(x)}{x^2}\,dx$$
$$4=-\frac12(243/81-36/36)+\frac12\int_6^9\frac{f'(x)}{x^2}\,dx=-1+\frac12\int_6^9\frac{f'(x)}{x^2}\,dx$$
$$\int_6^9\frac{f'(x)}{x^2}\,dx=2(4+1)=10$$

Comment: I am aware of integration of parts but I don't quite understand what you wrote. Would you mind explaining, please?

Comment: @user737163 It follows from the product rule: $(uv)'=uv'+u'v$. Integrate both sides and rearrange.

Comment: Oh, it was a typo. Got it. Thank you!